# How to merge the plots of 2 lift curves into a single graph in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn, scikit-plot

I produced a lift curve of answers predicted through 2 models: logistic regression and decision tree. I get 2 separate plots on two separate graphs. I need a single graph depicting both the plots. How to do that?

```
import scikitplot as skplt
log_y_probas = logmodel.predict_proba(X_test)
dec_y_probas = DecisionTreeModel.predict_proba(X_test);

skplt.metrics.plot_lift_curve(y_test,log_y_probas);
skplt.metrics.plot_lift_curve(y_test,dec_y_probas);
plt.show();
```

I receive two different plots on two different graphs. I need both the plots on the single graph. What should I do? Or should I use a different Python library somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, there is no need to end statements with semicolons.

Anyway, each call to `plot_lift_curve` returns an `Axes` object if the `ax` parameter is not specified. You can use that to plot both curves on the same `Axes`:

```
ax = skplt.metrics.plot_lift_curve(y_test, log_y_probas)
skplt.metrics.plot_lift_curve(y_test, dec_y_probas, ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you please tell if it is possible to add legends to the curve to depict which line corresponds to decision tree and which to logistic regression? If yes, how?

Comment: I actually haven't used `skplt` before, so I'm not sure what functionality it exposes for that kind of thing, but you can try to create your own legend (see the docs)!